# Ace editor snippet format for RegEx based triggers

Tags: regex, ace-editor

I'm using an array of snippets with following format

```
{
  name: 'response',
  trigger: 'resp|rp',
  path: ['paths', '.', '.', '.'],
  content: [
    '${1:code}:',
    '  description: ${2}',
    '  schema: ${3}',
    '${4}'
  ].join('\n')
},
```

How can I use a RegEx for the trigger? I tried `regex` key with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do via public api see [register](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.7/lib/ace/snippets.js#L549)  method of snippetManager, you can make it to work by accessing `snippetNameMap` directly, but it would be better to create feature request on Aces issue tracker.